# Increase Audio volume on Avi files

Tags: windows, audio, vlc-media-player, avi

Is there a simple way to adjust audio volume in avi files, like using MP3gain so i can set them all the same it is a problem having to keep adjusting the volume. I have tried VirtualDub but it doesnt handle my avi files as they are encoded in XVID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualDub handles XVID just fine if the necessary codecs are installed.

You may not have a VFW codec for XVID, which is the only type supported by VirtualDub.

Try for example [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_codec_pack.htm).

Comment: Codec packs are bad for my computer i would rather not install them

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that Xvid causes you problems with VirtualDub, as it's the sound you want to change, but it's been an age since I used that program. You can do it with Avidemux however (it supports Xvid, but you should be able to just copy the video directly anyway).

A couple of things to consider:

1. If you take a compressed signal (eg mp3 audio, JPG) and modify it, and recompress, you'll be losing something. (This might not bother you at all though.)

**Edit:** This next bit's wrong. It was my recollection of [this excellent article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/volume-in-windows-vista-part-1-what-is-volume) about volume in Windows Vista. But it applies to increasing the volume of signals that are already around the maximum volume that can be represented in their format, if I understand correctly.

2. As I understand it, there are limits to what you can do in software to a signal's volume. I used to have a good reference for that, but can't find it.

Comment: Thanks for the program your probably right and it will help, but how exactly do i use it?

Comment: Open the video file, choose _Copy_ under the __Video__ heading, choose an appropriate audio codec under the __Audio__ heading (eg. _MP3 (lame)_ - this is the target format, not the source format). Go to menu _Audio -> Filters_ and change the settings under __Gain__. HTH

Comment: Thanks for that is there any way of checking the current volume level for video files. The problem is some of my avi files are louder than the others, so with that program i can fix them to be the same audio level but how do i know the base audio level of each file?

Comment: Sorry, hadn't grokked what you really wanted to do. Try searching for _normalizing sound across multiple avi_ : you'll find loads of hits. Some for preprocessing the files, some for plugins that filter the audio as it plays.